# Where to find latest subversion url

Tags: svn

I am trying to install subversion on my Bluehost shared hosting account (though I use TortoiseSVN at work, this is my first attempt at using Subversion on my own site).

I found step-by-step instructions for using SSH to install Subversion on Bluehost accounts at [this url](http://www.calzzani.com/blog/?p=61), but when I got to the step where I have to enter the url to get subversion, I hit a brick wall. The article was written in 2011, so obviously doesn't have the latest version in the sample code.

I went to http://subversion.apache.org/download/ to see if I could find it, but I'm confused about where to find what I need. There's mention of source and binaries to download, but I don't need to download anything, just get the url to enter in the SSH session window.

Like others have mentioned, there are loads of tuts on installing subversion - even specifically on Bluehost, but none have the latest version.

**More Info**

At http://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release, the latest version is 1.8.3, but the tutorial has two wget lines with different urls to to different subversion files.

Further, there are three files at the downloads page I could get under the current version section - which one (or two or three) of those do I need to get?

Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: Then right-click on the link, and choose "Copy link address" (literal translation of the message in a French browser, but you should get the idea), and paste that URL where needed. wget will download it for you from this URL.

Comment: Thanks, JB, but that's just part of the answer - when I went to the subversion.apache.org site, I saw mention of binaries, source, and packages. What exactly do I need to install on the hosting server?

Comment: Given that the instructions continue with `make && make install`, we can safely assume that it's compiling and installing the software from the sources, and that what the guide uses is the sources, and not the binaries.

Comment: Okay, makes sense - I used `http://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release` from the downloads page, but I'm not sure what to do with the following `tar` commands, as they refer to specific files. `ls` lists just index.html, so I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: The correct link is http://apache.mirrors.multidist.eu/subversion/subversion-1.8.3.tar.gz: the link to the tar.gz to download. You'll have to change the name of the file to the actual file name: subversion-1.8.3.tar.gz.

Comment: Thanks! - if you put this into an actual answer, I'll mark it a such...